# Duplicate database queries and timeouts

Tags: craft3, queries, plugin-neo, timeout

I'm looking to get some advice on excessively duplicated database queries when selecting single types in Craft CMS

Our craft instance keeps timing out when trying to load the home page single entry, so I was doing some debugging locally with the debug toolbar and a fresh DB and noticed that we have over 800 duplicate queries for this entry (even on a fresh DB with no content), this seems a bit excessive?

Currently running:

- Craft Pro 3.7.15
- Neo 2.11.13
- Element API 2.8.0
- SuperTable 2.6.8
- SEO 3.4.15

Our home page only has 3 fields:

1. Title (text)
2. Seo (SEO Settings)
3. Blocks (NEO blocks) which has 36 block types

**If I remove the blocks field I get the following in the debug tool:**
[image]

**But if I re-add the NEO blocks field I get this:**
[image]

Are results like this normal? Especially when theres no content saved? These results are even worse in a PROD env when trying to load the home page entry with content.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Perhaps our implementation of Neo blocks is wrong and causing way to many queries?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: In the debug toolbar, sort the database queries by the duplicated column descending. Do the worst duplicated query offenders give you an idea of where they might be coming from? Can you edit the question to share some of them?

Comment: Hi @BradBell, thanks for your comment. I've added some extra screenshots of some of the queries. Worst offenders seem to be SELECT queries related to fields. Thanks heaps